# Password for which user SVN asks?

Tags: svn, authentication

I've logged in into our SSH server as `restoldyaffotst1` user.

Then (passwords and hashes replaced with PASSWORD and HASH):

```
$ svn checkout svn://svn:PASSWORD@svn.logostudio.co.il/logostudio/trunk/logo
Authentication realm:  HASH
Password for 'restoldyaffotst1': 
Authentication realm:  HASH
Username: ^Csvn: E200015: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://svn:PASSWORD@svn.logostudio.co.il/logostudio/trunk/logo'
svn: E200015: Caught signal
```

(I pressed Ctrl+C)

What the hell SVN asks me for `Password for 'restoldyaffotst1'` not the password for `svn` user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you are using is not valid. You will find no mention of it on the following pages:

[Repository access URLs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.wc.tbl-1)

[Command-line authentication](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.netmodel.html#svn.tour.initial.different-user)

From the output of `svn help checkout`:

```
checkout (co): Check out a working copy from a repository.
usage: checkout URL[@REV]... [PATH]

  If specified, REV determines in which revision the URL is first
  looked up.

  If PATH is omitted, the basename of the URL will be used as
  the destination. If multiple URLs are given each will be checked
  out into a sub-directory of PATH, with the name of the sub-directory
  being the basename of the URL.

....

Global options:
  --username ARG           : specify a username ARG
  --password ARG           : specify a password ARG
```